# Does "netstat -e" displays statistics of all network interfaces combined?

Tags: windows, networking, netstat

This is an example output of `netstat -e`:

[image]

Does this output displays the statistics of all the network interfaces combined, or does it only displays the statistics of a single network interface?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it displays all the network interfaces combined.